# Evaluate next row in sqlite3 iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

Can i access only the first row from the 'Select *' query. After the first row evaluation result i need to decide to call next now or not. We can achieve this by cursor in android. 
Can i achieve the same in sqlite3 iphone?

`if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)` -

Is it will call only one row or all the rows? For ex: I need to call one row and evaluate the value. After that by seeing the answer i need to call callNextRow().

So what code i need to write in callNextRow() method?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like:

```
while (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
  if(! your condition)
  {
     //condition not satisfied
     break;
  }
}
```

The following code will return only one row at a time,

```
if(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW)
```